# Ignore React Warnings on node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

For some reason my build is still catching and processing React warnings on code located in node_modules.  I want to disable that but not sure how it's still reading that code.

I am **not** using `componentWillMount` anywhere in my own code.  It's somehow picking it up in node_modules.

[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () =>
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: true,
    });

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () =>
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'lib/assets' },
            { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/autoload.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink-flex.min.css', to: 'lib/css' },
            { from: 'ext/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/fonts', to: 'lib/css/fonts' },
            { from: 'feed.xml', to: './' },
        ],
    });

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        writeToDisk: false,
        publicPath: '/',
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/',
        },
        stats: 'errors-only',
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
            },
        },
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: 'styles',
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: '../../',
                            outputPath: 'lib/css',
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|otf|svg)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: '/lib/css/fonts', // <--resolve the path in css files
                            outputPath: 'lib/css/fonts', // <-- path to place font files
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: isProduction
        ? [
                new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ]
        : [
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ],
};
```

Comment: also can anyone tell me why my code which has 2 space tabs is showing up with 4 when I paste code in stack?

Comment: Ever figure this one out?  I have webpack complaining at me about warnings from 3rd party libraries from the node_modules...ever find a way to quiet that, without quieting errors and warnings in your actual code?